# Getting empty pmd.xml - unable to copy several log files from project dir to workspace

Tags: jenkins, pmd

Addressing the issue of empty XML files of PMD/Clover, I have created build.xml in the root of a repository and changed its source so that it can run my test cases of another directory, like "tests".

When I run ant from the command prompt in the path where build.xml  is stored, all needed log files are created.

But when I create a new project from Jenkins and create a new build, my test cases run perfectly as per expectation; but i am not able to see any report except the HTML version. I would like to address the error I get, as follows:

```
Total time: 1 minute 37 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
[CHECKSTYLE] Collecting checkstyle analysis files...
[PMD] Collecting PMD analysis files...
[PMD] Skipping file  of module /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TestProject/workspace/build/logs/pmd.xml because it's empty.
[DRY] Collecting duplicate code analysis files...
Recording plot data
Publishing Clover coverage report...
Clover xml file does not exist in: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TestProject/workspace called: build/logs/clover.xml and will not be copied to: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TestProject/builds/2011-08-29_08-21-02/cloverphp/clover.xml
Could not find 'build/coverage/build/logs/clover.xml'.  Did you generate the XML report for Clover?
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at BUILD level /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TestProject/workspace/build/api to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TestProject/builds/2011-08-29_08-21-02/htmlreports/API_Documentation
ERROR: Directory '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TestProject/workspace/build/api' exists but failed copying to '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TestProject/builds/2011-08-29_08-21-02/htmlreports/API_Documentation'.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Starting to record.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Processing PHPUnit-3.4 (default)
[xUnit] [INFO] - [PHPUnit-3.4 (default)] - 1 test report file(s) were found with the pattern 'build/logs/junit.xml' relative to '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TestProject/workspace' for the testing framework 'PHPUnit-3.4 (default)'.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Stopping recording.
[JDepend] JDepend plugin is ready
[JDepend] Couldn't generate JDepend file at 'build/logs/jdepend.xml'java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TestProject/workspace/build/logs/jdepend.xml (No such file or directory)
ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.violations.ViolationsPublisher aborted due to exception
```

I've got a problem now. Although the steps to set up Jenkins for PHP is told to be completed in 15 minutes, unfortunately it is taking more than 2 days to run everything perfectly. Everything meaning getting all those charts, reports and graphs.

Comment: -1 for not responding to Boian's answer for close to a year.

Answer (score 4):

I hade the same issue while trying to install php support for jenkins.
Upper in your log you should see some warnings about x-debug.
try installing x-debug module, 
for ubuntu/debian you can try:

```
apt-get install php5-xdebug
```